# How do I use datatables in angular tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, tabs, datatables-1.10

I get the following errors after clicking the first and second tabs respectivly
"Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined"
and
"Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null"

[image: The Tab]

[image: Error when tab 1 openos]

[image: Error when tab 2 is clicked]

This is the TS code

[image: TS CODE]

[image: ANGULAR / HTML]

Answer (score 0):

Splitting each table into different angular components and using @ViewChild to call the dtOptions.ajax

@ViewChild(AllGigsTableComponent) allGigsChild:AllGigsTableComponent ;

```
   onSelectTab(index){
       if(index == 0) 
      {
        this.allGigsChild.dtOptions.ajax;
      }
   }

 <div class="table-responsive">
  
     <tabset type="pills">

      <tab heading='ALL' (selectTab)="onSelectTab(0)">

       <app-all-gigs-table></app-all-gigs-table>

    </tab>
</div>
```